# JS function for validation of the brackets in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, expression, brackets

guys! I want to ask you how can a make a function, that checks if the brackets in a string are put correctly. For example "(a + b).4,2 - )c + 5)" and I have to check the brackets. I tried something, but it doesn't seem to work(sorry, I'm a newbie in javascript):

```js
function checkBrackets(str){
 var newOrder = [];
 var bracket1 = "(";
 var bracket2 = ")";
 for(var bracket1 in str){
  
   newOrder.push("1");
 }

 for(bracket2 in str){
  
   newOrder.pop();
 }

 if(newOrder.length == 0){
  console.log("Right!" + newOrder);
 } else{
  console.log("Wrong!" + newOrder);
 }
}

checkBrackets('( ( a + b ) / 5 – d )');
```

I tried to loop through the string with a for-in loop and whenever it hits a "(" to add "1" to the array. And when it hits a ")" to remove one "1" from the array. At the end if the array is empty, i could conclude, that the brackets were put correctly and if not, they weren't.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use an array instead of a simple counter?

Comment: Nope, I just went straight to the array... I haven't thought of a counter. And I'm overall new to programming and to javascript.

Comment: Maybe you should try with a counter and see how that goes. Your main problem with the array method is that you can't `.pop()` an empty array.

Comment: The idea was that if I add "1" when the first bracket appears, i will remove it if the other one is there. So the array won't be empty

Comment: Yes, I get that. But when you have `(a + b).4,2 - )` the array *will* be empty when you hit the second `)`.

Comment: I'm so stupid *facepalm*... You are right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
// str is the string to parse
function checkBrackets(str){
    // depth of the parenthesis
    // ex : ( 1 ( 2 ) ( 2 ( 3 ) ) )
    var depth = 0;
    // for each char in the string : 2 cases
    for(var i in str){   
        if(str[i] == '('){
            // if the char is an opening parenthesis then we increase the depth
            depth ++;
        } else if(str[i] == ')') {
            // if the char is an closing parenthesis then we decrease the depth
            depth --;
        }  
        //  if the depth is negative we have a closing parenthesis 
        //  before any matching opening parenthesis
        if (depth < 0) return false;
    }
    // If the depth is not null then a closing parenthesis is missing
    if(depth > 0) return false;
    // OK !
    return true;
}
console.log(checkBrackets('( ( a + b ) / 5 – d )')); // true
console.log(checkBrackets('( ( ) a + b ) / 5 – d )')); // false
console.log(checkBrackets('( ) ) ( ( a + b ) / 5 – d )')); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've accepted an answer already, I felt it was a little complex, so I thought I'd expand on the naive solution I presented in the comments to the question:

```js
function checkBrackets(str) {
  // using a regular expression to find the number '(' characters in the string,
  // escaping with a '\' because '(' is a special character within a regular
  // expression; if no matches are found, and the result of 'match()' is falsey,
  // we instead assign an empty array (in order that calling 'length', later, on
  // a potentially-null object, won't create an error):
  var opens = str.match(/\(/g) || [],
    closes = str.match(/\)/g) || [];

  // if there are equal numbers of '(' and ')' characters, we return true,
  // otherwise false:
  return opens.length === closes.length;
}

// unnecessary, this is just a means of iterating over the <li> elements, to work on
// a range of inputs for the function:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), function(li) {
  // li is the <li> element/node itself, li.textContent is the text contained within
  // that <li>, using the classList API to add a 'valid' class (if brackets are balanced)
  // or an 'invalid' class (if the brackets are not balanced):
  li.classList.add(checkBrackets(li.textContent) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.valid {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>( ( a + b ) / 5 - d )</li>
  <li>( a + b ) / 5 - d</li>
  <li>( a + b ) / ( 5 - d )</li>
  <li>( a + b ) / 5 - d )</li>
  <li>a + b ) / 5 - d</li>
  <li>( a + b / 5 - d</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: Your solution is interesting but does not cover all cases : http://jsfiddle.net/okyxvz02/ This is why I used a counter (to prevent a closing before an opening parenthesis).

Comment: A fair point, but without clarification in the question as to what problem(s) he wants to solve, I went with my initial, and naive, assumption.

Comment: you're right, in the meantime I updated my code with some comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it to handle not just parentheses but other characters as well. If it's more than just parentheses you need to validate, then you need to implement a stack/array. You can also use the length of the stack instead of declaring a balance/depth/count variable.

```
function IsValid(text) {
  const leftBraces = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    const char = text[i];

    switch (Brace(char)) {
      case 'L':
        leftBraces.push(char);
        break;
      case 'R':
        if (!Match(leftBraces.pop() + char)) {
          return false;
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  return leftBraces.length === 0; 
}

function Match(brackets) {
  switch (brackets) {
    case '()': case '{}': case '[]':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

function Brace(c) {
  switch (c) {
    case ')': case '}': case ']':
      return 'R';
    case '(': case '{': case '[':
      return 'L';
    default:
      return ''; 
  }
}

console.log(IsValid('c[d]')) // true
console.log(IsValid('a{b[c]d}e')) // true
console.log(IsValid('a{b(c]d}e')) // false - ] doesn’t match (
console.log(IsValid('a[b{c}d]e}')) // false - nothing matches final }
console.log(IsValid('a{b(c)')) // false - no matching }
```